# How to redirect long string with single/double quotes var in Rundeck?

Tags: bash, redirect, rundeck

thank you for taking time reading this question.

I've a Rundeck job with multiple steps. Basically, step 1 and 2 is fetching a long string which is under `' '`. Example:
`'This is a long string.. and is also under "double quotes" '`. -> This variable is stored as the following form: `@option.mylongstring@`

Third step of my Rundeck job is failing because I'm having issues with single and multiple quotes in my string. I want to extract specific values from that long string

My solution was to send the content of `@option.mylongstring@` in a temp file and apply sed to convert single quotes into double quotes (`sed "s/'/\"/g"`) and from there, extract the information that I need.

Anyway, seems that the redirection is not happening in Rundeck: `echo @option.mylongstring@ &> $TEMPFILE` is doing nothing, generating an empty file.

Anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inline-script works without problems, let me share the job definition example:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>5e7123ce-c9b7-4bfa-a0e8-6484a9bd7c4f</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>LongStringExample</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[echo 'hello "world"' > myfile.txt]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>5e7123ce-c9b7-4bfa-a0e8-6484a9bd7c4f</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Using an option:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <context>
      <options preserveOrder='true'>
        <option name='opt1' />
      </options>
    </context>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>22d7286f-7be9-4aaf-92ae-8e5bf5277d67</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>AnotherLongStringExample</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[echo 'this is another "@option.opt1@"' > another_file.txt]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>22d7286f-7be9-4aaf-92ae-8e5bf5277d67</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Comment: the issue is that ```@option.mylongstring@``` is filled from a payload. That payload contains multiple single and double quotes inside and redirecting is not working

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible example job definition to test? I tested using this one and the text is saved in the file: https://pastebin.com/AcMSiSpj

Comment: Thank you so much. I resolved this issue using an environment variable passing to the file.